# poetry update [--lock] is not updating the poetry.lock file?

Tags: python, python-poetry

When I ran

```
poetry update
```

there were a few changes/updated libraries. But the *poetry.lock* file was unchanged.  Puzzled, I also tried

```
poetry update --lock
```

.  Likewise the  *poetry.lock* file was unchanged.   What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Maybe the lock file was already up to date, but not the installed packages in your environment?

Comment: The command said there were several changes

Comment: Maybe it meant there are several changes compared to your environment's packages? Are you sure it was comparing to the existing `poetry.lock`? Can you provide an example of one of the alleged updates, and check which version was still in `poetry.lock`?

Comment: @DaveLiu  The messages were clear about newer versions being installed. But the `poetry.lock` did not change.